# AngularJS function result as input value in mandrill EmailController

Tags: angularjs, mandrill

I started a new question because although the last question was answered successfully it has brought about new issues that i cant seem to fix..

i have two factory functions in OrderFunctions

```
total(menu)
```

and

```
totalOrder()
```

in the app these functions work great however when i try to submit the order form using mandrill in my EmailController. the calculated results are not sent. apart from this it has also seemed to effect the showAlert() function on successful send.

anyway as previously requested here is a plunkr

so the EmailController is in controller.js and you can see the html markup  in the order.html

thanks for looking

Comment: could you add a steps to reach at issue where you are getting problem?

Comment: sure on the menu view you click the fab+ button to add item then on option view you choose size and flavor.. then on order view everything is total correctly by the total(menu) function .... this total is not added to the EmailController  when the email is sent. it is recieved as $0.00 .... also now the showAlert() function is not firing.. but that is probably because of the email not being successfully sent

Comment: you missed to add `$scope.totalItems()` which throwing an error in console when i click on `Place Order` button

Comment: ok i see, i must have copied an older file before i added the totalItems()  into the factory.. i will update the plunkr when i get home.. however even with the function refrence removed from the EmailController it is still not recieving the result of total(mail)... thats wierd because it works within the app

Comment: @pankajparkar  ok i have updated the totalOrder(menu) function but the results of total(menu) and  totalOrder(menu) are still not passed to the EmailController. I would also be interested to hear any ideas you may have that are better suited for emailing the total order to the client.. in a perfect world i would like to send exactly as shown on the order page, but the best i can come up with is the totalOrder function... i have not yet been able to format the result any better than i have already.. anyway i thank you for your time and you have helped me alot lately...